# Why does my react-router Link not take me to the other page (React JS)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this code inside my App.js and i declared those routes:

```
function App() {
 return (
<BrowserRouter>
<div className='App'>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/"><Index /></Route>
    <Route exact path="/contact"><Contact /></Route>
  </Switch>
  
</div>
</BrowserRouter>
);
}

export default App;
```

And then in my Navbar.js i declared this link to /contact:

```
<Link to={ "/contact" } className="nav-item nav-link">Contact</Link>
```

And it doesn't work, the url changes into "http://localhost:3000/contact" but it remains in the index page, and the weird thing is that when i type exactly the same url in the url box it takes me to the contact page

Comment: could make a sandbox link of the issue

Comment: mmm idk how to do that sorry

Comment: Where is the Navbar ?

Comment: the navbar.js is in the components folder and the contact.js is in the pages folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax error.

You wrote : Link to={ "/contact" } but it will be like : `<Link to="/contact">Contact</Link>`

I think It will be solved.

Comment: nope i tried that too and still didn't work

Comment: Use Router version 6.

Answer (score 0):

Your code wrong it shold be like that: to="/contact"

Comment: i tried that too and didn't work either

Comment: Try to remove exact from contact route and did you import browser router from react router dom?

Comment: yes i imported Route and removed exact and it doesn't work, it became even worse

Answer (score 0):

Well I would alter the code slightly:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className='App'>
        <Routes>
          <Route index element={<Index />} />
          <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
        </Routes>
  
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The link code you have I've altered slightly too:

```
<Link to="/contact" className="nav-item nav-link">Contact</Link>
```

That's how we have ours and it is working fine, should be for you too.